# Enabling LaTeX shell escape in RMarkdown

Tags: yaml, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm working on an RMarkdown document that I want to compile with xelatex using the shell escape option.  The [RStudio documents](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532257-Customizing-LaTeX-Options) describe how this can be done for `*.tex` documents but the *Enable shell escape command* option does not appear to affect the compilation of Markdown documents.

Here's my YAML header.  Is there a way I can pass the `--enable-write18` option to the LaTeX engine by specifying it in the YAML?

```
---
title: "My document"
author: "Me"
date: "2016-01-01"
documentclass: report
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    template: ard-pandoc-template.tex
    toc: yes
---

# Test

asdfjkhasdf
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latex shell-escape options in YAML header don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459948/latex-shell-escape-options-in-yaml-header-dont-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer on another [RStudio page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#pandoc_arguments).  There's an option to pass additional arguments to Pandoc from the YAML header:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    pandoc_args: "--latex-engine-opt=--enable-write18"
```

Comment: --latex-engine-opt has been removed.  Use --pdf-engine-opt instead.

Comment: Also link to docs is dead. New link is [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#pandoc-arguments).

Comment: Actually this solution won't work anymore. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by OP doesn't work anymore.

To have `pdflatex` called with `-shell-escape` in a RMarkdown document, put the following inside the document:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
options(tinytex.engine_args = '-shell-escape')
```
````

The LaTeX engine is called by `tinytex::latexmk()` instead of Pandoc, so the Pandoc argument `--pdf-engine-opt` won't work.

[Source (and credit) here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660211/1719931).