# Latex shell-escape options in YAML header don't use

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm writing a report on Rmarkdovn but when you try to compile - pandoc_args options ignored when compile pdf.

I find this question:
[Is it possible to include svg image in pdf document rendered by rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064292/is-it-possible-to-include-svg-image-in-pdf-document-rendered-by-rmarkdown)

But it does not work because *--latex-engine-opt* replaced by *--pdf-engine-opt*. I replaced, but also did not work.

**Compilation command:**

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('test.rmd')"
```

**test.rmd**

```
---
title: Test
papersize: a4paper
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    pandoc_args: [
      --pdf-engine-opt, -shell-escape,
      --pdf-engine-opt, -interaction=nonstopmode]
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{minted}
---
```

**Output:**

```
processing file: test.rmd
  |................................                                 |  50%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options)
List of 1
 $ engine: chr "python"


output file: test.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.tex --template /home/renesat/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --pdf-engine-opt --shell-escape --pdf-engine-opt -interaction=nonstopmode --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes'
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

Error: Failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I can use knitr -> pandoc -> xelatex, but it would be more convenient to use YAML header.

Comment: This is because the second `--pdf-engine-opt` overwrites the first. Since you are using minted, may I suggest the [Lua filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/minted) writtern by Stephen McDowell?

Comment: @tarleb thanks for Lua filter. But line ```pandoc_args: [--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape]``` doesn't work either. Apparently I will compile while the script :) But it would be interesting to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R Markdown documents are compiled to PDF via `tinytex::latexmk()`. To enable the `-shell-escape` option for your LaTeX engine, you may set the global option `tinytex.engine_args`, e.g., add this code chunk to your document:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
options(tinytex.engine_args = '-shell-escape')
```
````

See the help page `?tinytex::latexmk` for more information.

The LaTeX engine is called by `tinytex::latexmk()` instead of Pandoc, so the Pandoc argument `--pdf-engine-opt` won't work.