# How to enable LaTeX shell-escape in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown, tinytex

I am writing a bookdown project using the LaTeX `minted` package to do code formatting. The `minted` package requires invoking `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option.

See the related question [Latex shell-escape options in YAML header don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459948/latex-shell-escape-options-in-yaml-header-dont-use)

I can do this in individual `.Rmd` files by putting `options(tinytex.engine_args = "-shell-escape")` in a startup chunk at the beginning of the document, but this doesn't seem to work when I invoke `bookdown::render_book("Index.Rmd", output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book")`.

I have tried setting `pandoc_args: "--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape"` in output settings the `_bookdown.yml` file

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    pandoc_args: "--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape"
```

but this doesn't work.

I can get the book to knit properly if I manually set `options(tinytex.engine_args="-shell_escape")` from the R console before running `bookdown::render_book`

```
library(bookdown)
options(tinytex.engine_args="-shell-escape")
render_book("Index.Rmd", output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book")
```

but I am wondering whether there is a way to set the `tinytex.engine_args` option programmatically from `_bookdown.yml` or one of my `.Rmd` files or something similar every time I run `bookdown::render_book`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the relevant statement to be executed is:

```r
options(tinytex.engine_args="-shell-escape")
```

The only solution to automate this seems to be including that line in an `.Rprofile` config file, that should be located in the root directory of your RStudio project. Hence:

1. Create a plain text file named `.Rprofile` in your project directory and insert the line of code mentioned above.
2. Close your project and reopen it with RStudio, to load global options in `.Rprofile`.
3. Build your book that includes some LaTeX package requiring that option (e.g. `minted`). Now, the book should compile without errors.

Other alternatives, like including the same line of code in a chunk inside the `index.Rmd` file do not work.